# for a long time+ negative?

Tags: word-order

Is it correct to say ''For a long time I haven't visited Tom'', without continuing the sentence? Isn't there any grammar rule to state that the order should be : ''I haven't visited Tom for a long time''?

It doesn't sound right to me. I feel like I need and affirmative sentence to follow ''For a long time'', if I don't give an explanation of my actions.

Maybe I'm just tired, It's almost 2am here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Adverbial phrases** can generally move around English sentences freely.  In cases like your sentence, the phrase *for a long time* can modify only the verb (here, *have visited*), so beginning or end, both positions in this case are available to mean the same thing.  This lets you write sentences like

> [1] **For a long time**, I haven't visited Tom, my older brother and the tallest of my siblings.

In [1], the compound appositive precludes other locations for the adverbial phrase, so it's a good thing the beginning of the sentence is available for it.

Note that sometimes, moving the adverbial phrase changes the meaning:

> [2a] **For a long time**, I haven't visited Tom, who has been a good friend.
>   [2b] I haven't visited Tom, who as been a good friend **for a long time**.

[2a] and [2b] mean different things.